# Weird deform Issue

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

When I try to rotate a bone on the arm the chest armor deforms as well. I looked around and couldn't find any answers, any help?

Also I did check weight paint and there is no reason the chest should be pulled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload the file.

Comment: sometimes the mesh appears blue but nevertheless there's an influence, you should select your chest armor and go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Group, then select the group that have the arm bone name and press Remove

Comment: I started deleting vertex groups and this started to work, i got some decent results. But when I delete the arm vertex group i can no longer deform it. I probably shouldn't have merged the armor into a single object..im gonna try seperating them out and see what i get

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to moonboots, i had vertex groups linked to the wrong bones. Thanks!